# What is the Debian equivalent of RPM's debuginfo and debugsource packages and how can they be found?

Tags: debugging, debian, debian-packaging

In the RPM world, debug symbols and the source code for a package are packaged in RPMs with names ending in `debuginfo` and `debugsource` respectively. These can be downloaded using the `dnf debuginfo-install` command.

In what kind of package will the symbols and the source code be found on a Debian derived system?

Where are these debug packages hosted if not in the main package archives, and what command is used to download and install them if not "apt install"?

Comment: Some libraries includes debuginfo directly in packages, or they provide an additional package with a suffix -dbg or -debug (or similar). `apt-get source` get the source (with all patches applied), but locally where you call the script, not where a debugger may expect the sources).

Answer (score 0):

There is no systematic distribution of debug symbols. If you want them, typically you would download the package sources with `apt-get source` and examine the build scripts to figure out how to get a locally built version with debug symbols etc.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think an equivalent to debugsource exists in Debian,
dbgsym packages provide debugging symbols.
Take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/AutomaticDebugPackages for more information.

TLDR: add something like

```bash
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-debug/ testing-debug main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-debug/ testing-proposed-updates-debug main
```

to your /etc/apt/sources.list (replacing “testing” with whatever version you are following)

run `apt update` to fetch those new package lists.
And install the wanted debugging symbols via something like

```bash
apt install libqt5qml5-dbgsym
```